# Avoiding Dynamic Type Casting with Inheritance for Data Classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, code-duplication

I have 3 Data Classes

```
@Data
class A
{
    private int a;
}

@Data
class B extends A
{
    private int b;
}

@Data
class C extends A
{
    private int c;
}
```

Class B and C have some common fields between them which is kept in their parent class A.
Following is the tester class

```
class TesterClass
{
    static String bOrC = "C"; // input from some decision
    public static void main(String[] args) // assume this to be the client
    {
        A a;
        if (bOrC.equals("B")) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setB(11);
            a = b;
        } else {
            C c = new C();
            c.setC(12);
            a = c;
        }
        a.setA(10);
        doSomething(bOrC, a);

    }

    // Below are the service methods
    // only this method in the service exposed
    public static void doSomething(String bOrC, A a) {
        if (bOrC.equals("B")) {
            doSomethingWithB(a);
        } else if (bOrC.equals("C")) {
            doSomethingWithC(a);
        }
    }

    public static void doSomethingWithB(A a) {
        B b = (B) a; // possible ClassCastException
        System.out.println(b.getA());
        System.out.println(b.getB());
    }

    public static void doSomethingWithC(A a) {
        C c = (C) a; // possible ClassCastException
        System.out.println(c.getA());
        System.out.println(c.getC());
    }
}
```

Now the problem I see with this is unsafe Dynamic Type Casting which can run into Class Cast Problems. One possible solution would be to create separate data objects and set the common fields (which are too many for my actual case) for both the objects separately in both classes B and C which would then look as follows:

```
public class TesterClass
{
    static String bOrC = "C"; // input from some decision
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (bOrC.equals("B")) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setA(10); // duplication
            b.setB(11);
            doSomethingWithB(b);
        } else {
            C c = new C();
            c.setA(10); // duplication
            c.setC(12);
            doSomethingWithC(c);
        }
    }

    public static void doSomethingWithB(B b) {
        System.out.println(b.getA());
        System.out.println(b.getB());
    }

    public static void doSomethingWithC(C c) {
        System.out.println(c.getA());
        System.out.println(c.getC());
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid this dynamic type casting but at the same time avoid having to duplicate the common variables. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Can't you just pass `B b` to `doSomethingWithB` and `C c` to `doSomethingWithC`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I have edited the code a little. Can you please check it again?

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction is one solution for the behavior you are explaining. Creating an abstract method doSomething(...) in class A and implementing it in child class B and C respectively. By doing this you don't need to have a static method and processing will be done bases on the instance of B or C objects itself.

```
    @Data
    class A
    {
        private int a;
        public abstract void doSomething();

    }

    @Data
    class B extends A
    {
        private int b;
        public void doSomething(){
/*.... do something here
* here you can also access parent public methods and properties.
* as you have already annotated with @Data you will have access to getA() method, * hence you can also use parent properties.
*/
        }
    }

    @Data
    class C extends A
    {
        private int c;
        public void doSomething(){
        /*.... do something here
        * here you can also access parent public methods and properties.
        * as you have already annotated with @Data you will have access to 
        * getA()         method, * hence you can also use parent properties.
        */

    }
```

Now you can use it as below

```
   public static void main(Strings[] args){
       A a;
       B b = new B();
       b.setB(10);
       b.doSomething();

       C c = new C();
       c.setC(30);
       c.doSomething();
   }
```

Comment: Hi Nimesh, can you please provide a sample code snippet based on my example? That would be very helpful